# Can an area under the following function exist?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

> Consider the function $S: [a,b] \cap \Bbb Q \to \Bbb R$ defined by $S(x)= x^2$. Does it make sense to speak about the area under the graph of $S$?

The Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral exists only if $S:[a,b]\cap \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. However $S(x)$ has many properties could make it "integrable".

### Properties of $S(x)$:

(1) The function is continuous.

The limit of $S(x)$ exists at any $c\in[a,b]$, if every $c$ is a cluster point of $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a dense in $\mathbb{R}$ the previous requirement is met and the limit exists at any point in the interval.

The continuity at $c$ would then exist if

\begin{equation}
\underset{x\in \mathbb{Q}}{\underset{x \to c}\lim} S(x)= S(c)
\end{equation}

which is true for $c\in \mathbb{Q}$. Since $S(x)$ is continuous in its domain, $S(x)$ is a continuous function.

(2)The function has no discontinuities

Continuous or discontinuous points exist in the domain. As mentioned earlier, the domain of $S(x)$ is continuous and hence there are no discontinuities.

Furthermore, the points where $x\not\in 
\mathbb{Q}$ are [removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) which are neither continuous nor discontinuous.

(3) If removed the requirement that $S:[a,b]\to{\mathbb{R}}$, for the Darboux sums to exist; the upper and lower sum would converge.

The function $S(x)$ is continuous on a set dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence if we divided $[a,b]$ into sub-intervals of partitions, no matter how small the sub-intervals, the supremum and infimum of $S$ at every sub-interval would exist.

\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\inf_{[x_j,x_{j+1}]}S(x)<\text{Area of $S(x)$}<\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sup_{[x_j,x_{j+1}]}S(x)
\end{equation}

Which is the same as

\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\inf_{[x_j,x_{j+1}]}x^2<\text{Area of $S(x)$}<\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sup_{[x_j,x_{j+1}]}x^2
\end{equation}

If the Darboux sum did not require $S:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ then $\text{Area of $S(x)$}= \int_{a}^{b} x^2 dx$.

### Conclusion

Could an area exist, without extending the domain of $S$ to the entire interval?

Should we change the definition of the Riemann integral so that $S:[a,b]\cap{A}\to\mathbb{R}$, where $A$ is dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, instead of $S:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The $S$ above is a set, not a function.

Comment: I think the intent was to define $S:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ by $S(x)=x^2$.  Or perhaps $S:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $S(x)=x^2\cdot \chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$. But yes, that notation is... odd.

Comment: Than how do I write $S(x)=x^2$ at rational numbers.

Comment: @copper.hat I made edits, is this any more clear?

Comment: @AlexM. The function is undefined when $x\not \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @Arbuja: Oh, I see, in this case you might want to roll back to the prevous version. But in this case your question also becomes very vague. You seem to be asking about a concept integral on $[a,b] \cap \Bbb Q$ such that the integral of a positive function should be the "area" (what would this even mean?) under the graph. Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: @AlexM. Yes that is what I meant

Comment: I am not really sure where exactly you want to get. Particularly since you seem to be hammering on the point that $S$ is continuous and defined on a dense subset of $[a,b]$; this points in the direction of the unique continuous extension of $S$ to $[a,b]$. This is also reinforced by the notion that you expect the 'area under $S$ ' to be the same as that of the area under its continuous extension to $[a,b]$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Yes, I think the area under $S$ should be the same as the are under the continuous extension. Would there be any problems if this were the case?

Comment: If that is your definition of the area under $S$, I don't believe there would be any problems. The thing is, you must **define** what 'area under $S$ ' means. Notice that $\mathbb{Q}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ (on $\mathbb{R}$), so if $S$ were not continuous -- meaning if there were no obvious extension to $[a,b]$ --, there might be some disagreement. Ultimately, I believe this is a matter of you defining what you mean by 'area under $S$ '.

Comment: This leads me to believe we could extend the lebesque measure so rationals by itself has a measure of 1. We could also create a new integral for discontinuous functions that are not defined everywhere (using new kind of measure). For example, if we set $0$ to defined on $\left\{\left.\frac{2p+1}{2^q}\right|p,q \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ and $1$ defined on $\left\{\left.\frac{2m+1}{2n+1}\right|m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$.

Answer (score 0):

In my definition, "the area under $S$" can exist in $[a,b]$ if the following requirements are met.

> 1. $S$ is a curve
> 2. The sets defined by $S$ have measure of one compared to sets outside of $S$.

The definition of a curve is the following.

> If $S:[a,b]\cap{A_n}\to\mathbb{R}$, such that $S$ is continuous in the interval and $A_n$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then $S$ is a curve.

Note that a functions may have more than one curve. Consider Dirichlet's function.
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x\in\mathbb{Q}\\ 0 & x\not\in{\mathbb{Q}} \end{cases}$$

We know $y=1$ is continuous everywhere and ${\mathbb{Q}}$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $y=0$ is continuous everywhere and irrationals is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Hence two curves exist.

The second requirement involves the measure of the sets defined by $S$. If $A_n$ has a measure of one compared to defined points outside the curve, then an area under $S$ has to exist.

In the case of the Dirichlet function, since the irrationals have a Lebesgue measure of $1$, the area under $0$ exists.

From this, I make my case that a function made of several curves does not have to be defined everywhere to have an area under one curve. Due to this, I am creating new measures where the area under curves of disconnected sets can exist.